# change hover color of specific menu link

Tags: menus, css

I'm trying to change a hover color of a menu link element.
Normally this is really easy, but on this projet i'm not able to do it.

*remove url*

I need to change the hover color of "RESERVER" button ( pink button in right header menu ) to another color.

I have tryed tons of CSS edit, no one works...

I'll really apreciate any help for this !

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: FYI: Even though the question has been edited, anyone on the Internet can still see the password you had posted here. I would recommend changing that password *immediately*.

Comment: thanks, its just a htpassword for Google, but you're true, i'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go -

```
.book-now-link span:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

Tested and it works.

Comment: i'm so stupid ^_^ i was targeting always a:hover ^^

Comment: @Gregory Glad it worked for you. Good luck!